# how to install g++ version under development

Tags: c++, linux, g++, apt, c++23

I can install `g++12` using

`apt-get install`

and

`apt-get update`.

But I would like to install the version that is actively under development to get the C++23 features as early as possible. The version is `g++13`.
According to
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support
`g++13` has some features of C++23 already implemented.
How can it be installed on linux ?

At least getting an up to date stl should be easy, though I don't know how to do even just that.

Comment: You either hope that your Linux distribution packages it somehow (unlikely), that you find a third-party repository for your distribution which packages it (maybe exists) or you build and install it yourself: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: You can find nightly builds on gcc.gnu.org, but this is not something you’re ever likely to be able to do through a package manager. Package managers exist for the 99%ers out there. https://gcc.gnu.org/snapshots.html

Comment: You could try clang instead: https://github.com/Vitorian/MyPasteBin/blob/master/build_clang_linux.sh

Comment: @Taekahn there are no nightly builds on gcc.gnu.org. There are weekly _source snapshots_ of the active branches, but not builds.

Answer (score 0):

> How can it be installed on linux ?

I provide Fedora and Ubuntu packages for the weekly snapshots of GCC's current development branch, see https://jwakely.github.io/pkg-gcc-latest/

That page has a link to a `.deb` file for Ubuntu, and instructions for enabling it in Github CI, and for using it in a container.

> At least getting an up to date stl should be easy, though I don't know how to do even just that.

No, you cannot use a new version of libstdc++ with an old GCC (or vice versa). You have to use matching versions, i.e. only use the version of libstdc++ that came with your GCC package.